# The syntax of the command is incorrect bat file

Tags: batch-file

I have the following code:

```
set originalDiractory = %1
set tableauReposetory = %2
set imageName = %3
set isFemale = %4

IF %isFemale% ==1(
copy /y "%originalDiractory%\User_Gender_Files\Female.png"  "%tableauReposetory%\%imageName%.png"
)
IF %isFemale% ==0(
copy /y "%originalDiractory%\User_Gender_Files\Male.png"  "%tableauReposetory%\%imageName%.png"
)
```

When I run it from `CMD` I get the following error:

```
C:\<path>>set isFemale = "0"
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
C:\<path>>IF 0 ==1(
```

What am I missing? whats wrong?

I add Apostrophes around the source and target still doesn't work

Comment: Put a space between the value and the paranthesis (`if %var%==1 (`)

Comment: Ahh i cant believe i fell on that, thanks seems to work

Comment: also avoid spaces when defining variables, `set imageName = %3` is not the same as `set imageName=%3` as the first creates a variable `imagename ` (trailing space) with the content of the third parameter with a leading space. Best practice is to enclose both `var name` and `var content` within quotes `set "imageName=%3"`. Also, if parameters come withing quotes, you may get rid of them (if you want) using `%~3`

Comment: there is no way that the code you show can produce the output you show.

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong, but i think you need your values right up close to the equal sign when using `set`.  maybe this will work `set isFemale=%4` and the others too

Answer (score 0):

You could adjust the structure of your provided code like this:

```bat
@Echo Off
If "%~4" NEq "1" (If "%~4" NEq "0" (Exit/B) Else Set "srcImg=M"
) Else Set "srcImg=Fem"
Copy /Y "%~1\User_Gender_Files\%srcImg%ale.png" "%~2\%~3.png" 2>Nul
```

This code, *as does yours*, assumes that the input arguments are satisfactory to the `Copy` command being run